# Animation with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move my left object till the red box and then hide it, then I want to show the right object just near the red box and then that object will also be move from red box to the right side of the page.
How to do this?
For explanation - click here
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfwQ9.png)

Comment: Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try transition property with transition delays like this

For more information read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

```css
 

.a {
    left :0;
    transition: left 2s linear 0s, opacity 0s linear 2s;
}
.b {
    left :50%;
}
.c {
    left: 50%;
    transition: opacity 0s linear 2s, left 2s linear 2s;
    opacity: 0;
 
}
.a.animate {
    left :50%;
    opacity: 0;
}
.c.animate {
  
  left: 96%;
  opacity: 1;

}
```

```html
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="position: relative;">
       <img alt="a" class="a" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zp1wNDsbqzc/Tgt-8JzobhI/AAAAAAAAAFs/0DI03F1p8OQ/s1600/hhhfd.gif" style="width: 10%;position: absolute;">
       <div  class="b" src="s" style="width: 10%;position: absolute;height: 100px;width: 100px; background-color: green;z-index: 10;"></div>
       <img alt="c" class="c" src="https://www.jamiesale-cartoonist.com/wp-content/uploads/cartoon-business-man-free1.png" style="width: 10%;position: absolute;">
</div>
<button id="abc" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    Activate
</button>

<script>
$("#abc").on("click", function() {
 $(".a").addClass("animate")
  $(".b").addClass("animate")
  $(".c").addClass("animate")
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check updated answer please

Comment: Please answer my this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772815/logo-and-navbar-over-video-and-should-be-responsive

Comment: A little busy right now. Will look into it in around an hour. :)

Comment: ok thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Just challenged myself. You can use absolute positioning in a relative positioned container, and animate the absolute position of each other with a delay at the second object.

```css
.all_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.man_prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-name: man_prev;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.red_box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* to center it */
  top: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
}

.man_next {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* to center it */
  top: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-name: man_next;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes man_prev {
    from {left: 0;}
    to {left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);}
}

@keyframes man_next {
    from {left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);}
    to {left: 100%; transform: translateX(-100%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="all_container">
  <div class="man_prev"></div>
  <div class="red_box"></div>
  <div class="man_next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. It works. But do you know how to run this animation in loop mode?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: yes. Thanx again

Comment: You can accept it if you think this is the correct answer.

Comment: I want to ask one more question, not regarding this, but system is not allowing me to do so.

Comment: I want to create a full screen video as a background and upon that I want to add bootstrap navbar and in the center of the screen, I want to add one logo. And when we scroll down then there will be one footer. I tried but the video is not getting responsive. SO can you please help me out.

Comment: You need to create a new question.

Comment: I don't know why the system doesn't let you open a new question. What does it say?

Comment: It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon! 
You've asked 1 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely
It's been 2 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 1 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.

Comment: Ok you do that then. It's the policy of this website to prevent spam questions.

Comment: Hello, in the above question , I want to first hide green box , after that blue box should appear in the infinite. How to do that?

Comment: Hi, you need to create a new question as I said before. This question of yours is answered before so changing the accepted answer won't make a difference. Please don't continue asking on this question anymore.